# Spring WebFlux - Return Custom Query Select

Tags: java, spring, h2, spring-webflux, r2dbc

I am learning Spring WebFlux.
I am trying to return a List from this query using the r2dbc repository that shows me the number of sales in each category.

```java
@Query("SELECT COUNT(sales.id)as salesnumbers, sales.type_contract as typecontract FROM sales" + " GROUP BY sales.type_contract")
```

This is my entity: Sales

```java
@Table("sales")
public class Sales implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column("salesdate")
    private Instant salesdate;

    @Column("type_contract")
    private TypeContract typeContract;

    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "sales" }, allowSetters = true)
    @Transient
    private Software software;

    @Column("software_id")
    private Long softwareId;
}
```

Any suggestion: How can I return this list?

Comment: It would really help if you could show your code and explain what you are trying to achieve in more detail.

Comment: Sure, I ll edit it

Comment: How can count be an instant?

Comment: @Toerktumlare I don't get what did you say,I build this query to show the number of sales : this is my first version  @Query("SELECT COUNT(sales.id),sales.type_contract FROM sales" + " GROUP BY sales.type_contract")

Comment: Your as alias in query does not match with your annotation can you make it same and try once